# Problems with tocloft-package: replace commands

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocloft

I am finally finishing my bachelor thesis and trying to get my list of tables and list of figures into my table of contents.
I used the options `bibliography=totocnumbered, listof=totocnumbered`

Bibliography works great, but the command `listof=totocnumbered` does not.

I read the problem is the package `tocloft`. If I comment the package out it works.
My Problem is that i got a template which use some commands of that package. I unfortunately, I dont know how to replace/ substitute them :/

Hope somebody can help me, I am LaTeX beginner and a little bit lost.

```
%\renewcommand{\cftdot}{} %no leading docs

\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}

%Chapter und section Schriftformat

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries\Large}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries}

%Chapter und section Seitenzahl-Format

\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries\Large}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\bfseries}

%Einrückungen der Ebenen

\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{section}{1.5em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{3em}{2.5em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{4.5em}{2.5em}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}
```

Comment: Which document class do you use? And, *where* did you "read [that] the problem is the package tocloft"?

Comment: Oh sorry, just realised i forgot to write my documentclass. I am using the scrreprt class. And I read it here: http://www.golatex.de/listoftotoc-funktioniert-ebensowenig-wie-liststotoc-t6008.html

Comment: @muella91: The KOMA classes have their own way to handle ToC - related content etc. You should **not** use `tocloft` in addition to a KOMA - class.

Comment: Please show a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) instead of a code snippet or see the [KOMA-Script manual](http://www.komascript.de/scrguide) for information about how to configure entries to the table of contents using `\RedeclareSectionCommand`.

Answer (score 2):

You are posting some code which just seems not necessary with KOMA-Script. Don't use the `tocloft` package and comment out all `\cft...` commands in the preamble.

Check the layout, if you'd like to change the appearance of something. With KOMA-Script, this can usually be done with `\addtokomafont`. You get the German manual with `texdoc scrguide` on the command line, at least, if you have TeX Live installed.

If you'd like to change the name of the table of contents (in German: Inhaltsverzeichnis), you'll probably need something like

```
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Übersicht}}
```

Cave: `\captionsngerman`, note the first "n".

Answer (score 2):

With `scrreprt` you can use the possibilities of KOMA-Script to format the TOC. The following suggestion needs at least version 3.20 (current is 3.22):

```
\documentclass[
  listof=totocnumbered
]{scrreprt}[2016/05/10]

\deftocheading{toc}{%
  \markboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}%
  \thispagestyle{\chapterpagestyle}%
}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocnumwidth=2em,
  tocentryformat=\bfseries\Large,
  tocpagenumberformat=\bfseries\Large,
  toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill
]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=1.5em,
  tocnumwidth=2em,
  tocentryformat=\bfseries,
  tocpagenumberformat=\bfseries
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=3em,
  tocnumwidth=2.5em
]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=4.5em,
  tocnumwidth=2.5em
]{subsubsection}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

See also [the answer of your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335097/43317).