# TOC Space between heading and contentsname

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocstyle

I want to reduce the spacing between the heading and the contentsname or the contentsname and the TOC.

I am using the `scrreprt` class and the `tocstyle` package. I couldn't find a command in the `tocstyle` documentation. Hope that's enough information, think a MWE is here not needed.

Okay, here is a picture of my toc:
I am trying to reduce the space between "Einleitung" and the heading.
I dont need a toctitle, so i turned it of \renewcommand{contentsname}{}

Dont find any commands in the tocstyle docu to "abovechapterskip" etc.
[image]

Comment: Hi, perhaps a picture of what you are referring to might help to make your question clearer.

Comment: Search for abovechapterskip and belowchapterskip in the documentation.

Comment: okay thank you. Didnt find a abovechapterskip or belowchapterskip.

Comment: See the answers to your other questions: [Tocloft, modify table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335097/43317) and [Problems with tocloft-package: replace commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356333/43317).

Answer (score 1):

To change the skip before and/or after the chapter heading only for the TOC heading you can use

```
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[
    beforeskip=1sp,% at least 1sp
    afterskip=1sp% at least 1sp
  ]{chapter}%
}
```

But if you want to remove the heading of the TOC complettly use `\deftocheading`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tocstyle}

\deftocheading{toc}{%
  \markboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}%
  \thispagestyle{\chapterpagestyle}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can redefine the `\tableofcontents` macro to use the star version of `\listoftoc`, which does not print the title at all:

```
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\listoftoc*{toc}}
```

Note also that `tocstyle` was a beta feature, and is being replaced by `tocbasic`.